# convert a list to other type

Tags: java

I have this interface and classes:

```
interface I {
    void method1();
}
class A implements I  {
    void method1(){
    ....
    }
}
```

Assume I have this list: `List<A> aslist` filled with A items, and I have a variable of type `List<I> vari=null;`
I need ti do `vari=aslist`? How can I do it with the minimum convertions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. A `List<Car>` is not a `List<Vehicle>`. If it was, you could do the following:

```
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
List<Vehicle> vehicles = (List<Vehicle>) cars;
cars.add(new Bicycle());
```

and it would thus completely break the type-safety of the collection.

What you can do is the following:

```
List<? extends Vehicle> vehicles = cars;
```

Comment: Well, you can create a covariant immutable view on the list, though.

Answer (score 4):

No, you should not cast `List<A>`. 
You just should define the list as `List<I>` from the beginning. You can then add instances of `A` to this list because `A` implements `I`:

```
List<I> list = new ArrayList<I>();
list.add(new A());
```

Other code can treat this list as `List<I>` and each its element as `I` without knowing the concrete implementation.

Comment: I get the List<A> from hibernate result and therefore cannot use List<I>.

Answer (score 4):

If you are unwilling to change the type of your list, you will have to create a shallow copy:

```
List<I> vari = new ArrayList<I>(aslist);
```

You can also use [`Collections.unmodifiableList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html?is-external=true#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29):

```
List<I> vari = Collections.<I>unmodifiableList(aslist);
```

That way, you don't need a copy, but the resulting list is immutable (to prevent the problematic usage described by JB).

Comment: The above doesn't compile (at least under Java 6). It needs to be changed to `Collections.<I>unmodifiableList(aslist)`. +1, though. I never noticed you could do that with `unmodifiableList()`.

Comment: @JB: Thanks for the correction, I don't code Java very often :)

Answer (score 2):

```
// If you don't care about some compiler warnings and know about the possible side effects that might arise if you continue to use "aslist" then:

List<A> aslist = ....;
List<I> vari = (List<I>)((List)aslist);

//Otherwise every single element must be copied. Is a one-liner though:
List<A> aslist = ....;
List<I> vari = new ArrayList(aslist);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
java.util.Collections.copy(vari, asist);
```